# Microsoft.Maui.Essentials keeps getting downgraded after Build

Tags: maui, nuget-package

In the CSPROJ it shows as:

```
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Maui.Essentials" Version="8.0.6" />
```

It also shows this version under Packages. However, after I build, Packages shows it as 8.0.3 and I get the error:

```
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Maui.Essentials from 8.0.6 to 8.0.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
AndroidAppCore -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls 8.0.6 -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Core 8.0.6 -> Microsoft.Maui.Core 8.0.6 -> Microsoft.Maui.Essentials (>= 8.0.6)
```

When I go into Nuget package manager and upgrade again, its fine until I do a Clean & Build. Then it repeats this whole cycle.

I also have this in my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
    <SupportedOSPLatformVersion>23</SupportedOSPLatformVersion>
    <UseMaui>True</UseMaui>
    <UseMauiEssentials>true</UseMauiEssentials>
```

I read the article here, but it didn't seem to help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605

What do I need to do?

Comment: I actually created an empty `.NET8` project and installed the package [Microsoft.Maui.Essentials](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials/#dependencies-body-tab) with version `8.0.6`. There's no warning or error when build the project. You may need uninstalled the old nuget package and directly added the [Microsoft.Maui.Essentials](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Essentials/#dependencies-body-tab) with version `8.0.6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went into the .csproj and noticed it showed as Upgrade= instead of Include=. I changed it to Include= for the package and the error no longer happens.

Comment: Excellent! You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.